# Is there a way to match before and after specified characters in RE2?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, re2

I need to find numbers within a larger document that may be credit card details, e.g. `346490606109917`. I want to ignore larger numbers that contain credit-card style details within them, e.g. `96213464906061099171`.

In regular RegEx (if you'll excuse the pun), I could use `(?<![0-9])` at the start of the pattern and `(?![0-9])` at the end, so that only numbers which exactly matched the credit card format would be matched, and larger numbers that may have credit card style numbers within them would be ignored. Non-numeric characters on either side of a number are fine.

My pattern is

```
(?<![0-9])(4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})(?![0-9])
```

which in normal RegEx would produce a match on `abc346490606109917zyz` but not on `abc96213464906061099171xyz`, for example.

However, [this isn't supported in Regex2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), which is what BigQuery uses - it's listed as "not supported" in the documentation.

Is there an equivalent in RE2, or is it impossible?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - I have, unless I'm misunderstanding your comment. `abc346490606109917zyz` would match againt `346490606109917` using the above pattern, whereas `abc96213464906061099171xyz` wouldn't produce any matches.

Comment: That pattern of yours [does not match the string you provided](https://regex101.com/r/BbiRfP/1). But what you need can easily be obtained using `(?:^|[^0-9])(your+pattern+here)(?:$|[^0-9])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew- It matches the first string but not the second, as said above - that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'abc346490606109917zyz' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc96213464906061099171xyz'
)
SELECT *, REGEXP_CONTAINS(str, r'(^|[^0-9])(4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})($|[^0-9])') check
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

result is below

```
Row str                         check    
1   abc346490606109917zyz       true     
2   abc96213464906061099171xyz  false
```

The `(^|[^0-9])` part identify either start of string or non-digits sequence. Same for `($|[^0-9])` but instead of start it indicates end of string or non-digits sequence

In case if you also need to extract card number  - use below as an example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'abc346490606109917zyz' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc96213464906061099171xyz'
)
SELECT *, 
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(str, r'(^|[^0-9])(4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})($|[^0-9])') check,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(str, r'(?:^|[^0-9])(4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})(?:$|[^0-9])') number
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

result will be

```
Row str                         check   number   
1   abc346490606109917zyz       true    346490606109917  
2   abc96213464906061099171xyz  false   null
```

Here, in `REGEXP_EXTRACT` you need to use `(?:regular_expression)` to indicate non-capturing group